# DSResponse data is expected to be an array of ListGridRecords error

Tags: java, gwt, record, smartgwt, listgrid

I'm working on a **GWT** app . I have this method :

```
public void executeFetch(final String requestId, final DSRequest request, final DSResponse response) {
        Record[] list;
        list = new Record[3];
        //
        Record rec1 = new Record();

        rec1.setAttribute("id", "-1");
        rec1.setAttribute("name", "All");
        list[0] = (rec1);
        //
        Record rec2 = new Record();
        rec2.setAttribute("id", "A");
        rec2.setAttribute("name", "Active");
        list[1] = (rec2);
        //
        Record rec3 = new Record();
        rec3.setAttribute("id", "C");
        rec3.setAttribute("name", "Inactive");
        list[2] = (rec3);
        //
        response.setData(list);
        processResponse(requestId, response);
    }
```

When debuging I see this warning :

> WARN:Log:setData(): DSResponse data is expected to be an array of
>   ListGridRecords. This allows the data to be displayed as expected in
>   ListGrids bound to this dataSource.

I don't get where the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a ListGridRecord instead of Record
https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGridRecord.html